# How duplicate the same map on scroll?

Tags: c#, maps, desktop-application, gmap.net

Can give me some advice's how i can make the same result in GMap.NET ? And how it effect is called ?

[Need the same effect at GMap.NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxHJb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays this features not supported by the library.
[Proof](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/657081#editor)